# Speed up for-loop data.table

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I have a grocery shopping dataset with 817.741 transactions and 12 variables, looking like this:

```
        Date Customer_ID Age_Group Address Product_Subclass   Product_ID Quantity Asset Price Price_Per_Unit Profit_Per_Item Budget_Item
1: 2000-11-01 00:00:00       46855        D       E            110411 4.710085e+12        3    51    57             19               6       FALSE
2: 2000-11-01 00:00:00      539166        E       E            130315 4.714981e+12        2    56    48             24              -8        TRUE
3: 2000-11-01 00:00:00      663373        F       E            110217 4.710266e+12        1   180   135            135             -45        TRUE
```

I have initialized the variable "Budget Item" by:

```
Total_Input[,"Budget_Item"] <- FALSE
```

Now I want Budget Item to be "True" in case (Price - Asset < 0). I did this through a for-loop, but running times are very long.. Any suggestions how to do this more time&memory efficient?

Current code for-loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Total_Input)){
  if(Total_Input$Price[i] - Total_Input$Asset[i] <0){Total_Input$Budget_Item[i] = TRUE}
}
```

Comment: `Total_Input$Budget_Item <- (Total_Input$Price - Total_Input$Asset) < 0`

Comment: @akrun, yes my dataset is data.table, confirmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a data.table, we can do

```
library(data.table)
Total_Input[, Budget_Item := (Price - Asset) < 0]
```

If there are missing values in 'Price', 'Asset', then we can also create the condition

```
Total_Input[, Budget_Item := ((Price - Asset) < 0 ) & !is.na(Price - Asset)]
```

---

Also, we don't need to initialize the 'Budget_Item' to `FALSE`.  It can be directly created by taking the difference of the columns ('Price - Asset'), convert it to `logical (` < 0`) vector and assign (`:=`) to create the column

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, very helpful. Any comments on why this works faster?

Comment: not sure why that happens as I upvoted your suggestion, i'm very thanksful for your help

Comment: @Rob Could you edit your post saying that your data is `data.table` class